# XElement DataType to Newtonsoft.json

Tags: c#, json, linq-to-xml, json.net

I'm new in json and got some problems trying to serialize my objects with specific data types.

I'm trying to serialize my XElement object into Newtonsoft json. Here is my code:

```
var nodes = new XElement("nodes");
nodes.Add(new XElement("name", "Anna"));
nodes.Add(new XElement("group", 0));

context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(nodes, Formatting.Indented, true));
```

the response is:

```
{
 "nodes": [
  {
    "name": "Anna",
    "group": "0"
  }
]}
```

I need  the Xelement GROUP converted to integer ("group": 0) but it is always in strnig format. How can I manage data types?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If serializing from XElement is not a must, you can use `ExpandoObject`

```
dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
obj.nodes = new object[] { new { name = "Anna", group = 0 } };

var jstr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

Answer (score 1):

See: [How to XML Serialize a 'Type'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290867/how-to-xml-serialize-a-type)

XML does not serialize type information, so you may need to deserialize your XML into an object and serialize that into JSON.